# Every second web service call

Tags: java, python, twisted

I need to write a short script that can consume a REST call, every second.  Most of the time, it will get back a response with:

```
"status": "idle"
```

However, if something is happening, we will instead get "status": "scan", with some additional parameters.

We consume those parameters, and then make a different call to a cloud service.

We would then get a response from that, and send back the JSON to the local web service.

Then once completed, it should go back to checking every second for a status other than idle.

1. Is Python a good language to do this on, or should be be using Java?
2. The every second call is over a LAN, not concerns over latency or internet bandwidth.
3. If it crashes or gets an exception we need to be able to restart easily.

Any pointers on this would be most appreciated.

The response coming back is in the format:

```
[{'status': 'idle', 'log_updated_at': None, 'eprom_version': '03.21', 'data': {}, 'controller_type': 'single_ball', 'address': 1}]
```

I am having some challenges getting that understood as json, to have the status element be accessed by the logic below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
import requests

while True:
    try:
        r = requests.get(local_rest_url)
        json_data = r.json()

        if json_data.get('status') == 'idle':
            time.sleep(1)  # wait 1 second
            continue       # and try again

        r = requests.post(cloud_service_url, data=json_data)
        cloud_response = r.json()

        r = requests.post(local_rest_url, data=cloud_response)
    except Exception:
        pass  # any error, just ignore and restart the loop
```

Comment: So nearly works...

    [jamie@MacBook-Pro-4 Documents]$ python egm.py
    <Response [200]>
    [{u'status': u'idle'

doesn't like the unicode in the response.

Sorry to be so basic, my first ever python script...

Comment: I don't understand the new problem. Unicode is good, everybody likes unicode. please edit the question and add more information

Comment: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

comes back in the response.  From a quick search this is because it sees it as a list?

r = requests.get("http://192.168.1.48:8080/api")
        json_data = r.json()
        print json_data
        if json_data.get("status") == 'idle':

Comment: @JamieAbbott then your response is not a `{"status": "idle"}` mapping as you said in the question - You're getting a list instead. You have to fix the code to deal with the data you're getting from the service.

Comment: thanks @noskio - issue was running Python 2.7 on OSX, rather than 3 which handles unicode properly.  Thanks for your help.